# Integral of exponential

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have been reviewing complex analysis since it's been awhile since I dove into it I am stumped of the following integral, $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{iax-bx^2}dx.$$ By setting $z=x-i\frac{a}{2b}$, I can assume that $a,b$ are real and that $b>0$ and I can use that $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-by^2}dy=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can complete a square to the exponent
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp \Big( iax-bx^2 \Big) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp \Big( -b \big(x^2- \frac{iax}{b} + \frac{a^2}{4b^2} - \frac{a^2}{4b^2} \big) \Big)dx \\
= \exp \Big( -\frac{a^2}{4b} \Big) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp \Big( -b \big(x - \frac{ia}{2b} \big)^2 \Big)dx
$$

Now substitute $t = \sqrt{b}(x-ia/2b)$ and we get
$$
\exp \Big( -\frac{a^2}{4b} \Big) \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2} \frac{ dt}{\sqrt{b}} = \exp \Big( -\frac{a^2}{4b} \Big) \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}} .
$$

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to integrate $e^{iaz - b z^2}$ around a rectangular contour with corners at $-R$, $R$, $R + i a/(2b)$ and $-R + i a/(2b)$, then taking $R \to +\infty$.